# Does it make sense to show the create button only if there are changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface

We have a simple form for creation of a new `Article` object and it has few attributes which needs to be populated. Would it make sense to show the create only if any attribute was filled? Are there any rails applications which behave this way

Answer (score 2):

I think it's relatively common to disable the create button until all information has been correctly entered, but be sure to include helpful messages either at the top of the field, next to fields which require editing, or both. You want it to be clear to the user why you've disabled the button.

However, hiding the create button entirely might be confusing. I think there are good reasons to not do that, and I don't recall seeing that in the wild.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the situation, but I would prefer doing extra validations instead of hiding the show button because it will confuse people. A create button simply tells the purpose of the page.